# ag-grid table spilling out of screen

Tags: html, angular, angular8, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid table that changes its size dynamically based on some buttons. more or less columns will be added or removed from the table. However, as the number of columns increases, the table would eventually spill out of the page, which cannot be seen. I have tried to apply horizontal scrolling but to no avail.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row text-center" style="justify-content: center;">
  <div>
    <ag-grid-angular
      style="font-size: 15px; width: 100%;"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="data"
      [columnDefs][="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColumnDefs"
      (gridready)="onGridReady($event)"
    </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want either two of the followings:

1. the width of the ag-grid table to be fixed and horizontal scrolling enabled
2. OR the width of the ag-grid table can grow depending on the number of columns. However, it should not spill out of the page.

And also, I would like the table to be centralized in the middle of the page as well.
Thanks!

Comment: could you reproduce your situation on plunk? it would be easier to provide solution for that as the issue here is very subjective to the CSS you've applied.

Comment: i have not applied any CSS at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<ag-grid-angular
      style="font-size: 15px; width: 100%;"
      class="ag-theme-balham"
      [rowData]="data"
      [columnDefs][="columnDefs"
      [defaultColDef]="defaultColumnDefs"
      (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
      (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```
onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
  params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}

onGridSizeChanged(params: GridSizeChangedEvent) {
  params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
```

I see your grid takes 100% width, make sure the parent div has a fixed width. To center the grid, I see you have done `justify-content: center;` which is good but make sure this div has `display: flex;` on it.

`gridSizeChanged` will be called every time the grid size changes and then we call `sizeColumnsToFit` so this will shrink all columns to fit with the fixed width.

Comment: I tried to apply the changes you suggested - onGridReady() and onGridSizeChanged(), included display: flex; and added width: 100% to the parent div. But i also took out the class="row text-center" in the parent div.

There is very slight changes but the behaviour of the table spilling out of the page still remains. Somehow, i cannot get the scrolling bar to appear or work.

Comment: I don't think adding `width: 100%` to parent div will fix it, try setting a hard value like `width: 1000px;`